# Prevent Hibernate N+1 Selects when grouping by an entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a Hibernate Criteria object that I build thusly:

```
Criteria obsCriteria = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory()
  .getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Observation.class);

ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.rowCount())
  .add(Projections.avg("value").as("avgScore"))
  .add(Projections.avg("type.score"))
  .add(Projections.max("date"))
  .add(Projections.groupProperty("observedSubject"));
criteria.setProjection(projection);
```

This produces a correct result for me, but the "observedSubject" property is an entity.  When I set set show_sql to true, I saw that after the first query (which returned 18 rows) there were 18 selects to get the observedSubject entities.  I've tried:

```
criteria.setFetchMode("observedSubject", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

But that didn't work.  As kind of a stab in the dark, I tried:

```
criteria.createAlias("observedSubject", "observedSubject", Criteria.FULL_JOIN);
```

But that didn't work, either.  Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate `observedSubject` to `FetchType.LAZY`?  If not, Hibernate is reverting to default behavior, which is `EAGER` fetching.

If you *do* want the child association fetched at runtime, but you don't want separate `SELECT` calls for each association, set `@BatchSize` on the association and Hibernate will batch the `SELECT` calls, making things more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at answering this languishing question.  I do need the data in the ObservedSubject - that's why it's added to the projection list.  I tried the @BatchSize annotation you suggested, but I don't think it's going to apply to queries like this using the Criteria API is it? One approach I thought of was to create a view with all the joins I want (including fields from observed subject) and creating an immutable entity based on that view.  That saves the N+1 queries, but it's not very close to what I was attempting before, so I am still wondering if there's a way to do it.

Comment: Yes, `@BatchSize` does work for Criteria queries.  I've set '@BatchSize(size=16)' on the Get method for a child association, and Hibernate used `IN` (in groups of 16) instead of `=` when fetching the children.  The way to do it is to first get the parents, and then loop the list, getting the children:
 `for(Parent p : parents) {
  if(p.getChildren() != null) {
   p.getChildren().size(); // forces the load
  }
 }`

Comment: The first part of your comment sounds like what I want, but then I'm confused by that last part.  The 'N' in 'N+1' is the number of parents in this scenario, so if I have to loop through the parents, it would still do the N+1 queries (which is what it looked like to me after I applied @BatchSize).

Comment: Maybe I'm confused.  Your original post sounded like you wanted to load the child associations, but didn't want separate SQL calls for each parent object, which is why I recommended `BatchSize`.  Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: I probably confused you with my last comment, but this isn't really a parent-child thing.  I'm grouping by observedSubject, so there will only be one observedSubject per row returned.  However, when I run the query, it returns all the rows, then fetches the observedSubject (a Person entity) once per row.

Comment: Got it (apologies for my density).  Perhaps if you specify a particular field from the `observedSubject` object (e.g., `observedSubject.name`), Hibernate will JOIN and not do separate SELECTs.  Then again, if you need the entire `observedSubject` object, this suggestion is moot.